# Any other way to get auto-extensble besides dba_data_files?

Tags: oracle, default, tablespace

To find one's default tablespace, an Oracle user can query [the user_users table](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Table/Getdefaulttablespaceforcurrentuser.htm).  They can also get their default temporary tablespace name from there, too.

But, when getting **details** of one's default tablespace, users must be granted "read" privileges on dba_data_files, which makes some companies' DBAs cringe.

It took me a really long time to finally find a page that alerted me to the previously mentioned user_users table to locate the default tablespace names.  Though I feel I have exhausted this search, does anyone know of an alternative to granting a user "read" permissions on dba_data_files to garner if the default tablespace is auto-extensible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to determine whether one or more data files are auto-extensible?  That's something that tends to be pretty deep into the weeds of what the DBA team deals with (the choice between making it auto-extensible and monitoring disk space at the OS level to make sure you're not running out vs. manually extending and monitoring how full your tablespaces are).

Comment: Because it is a requirement of our software of which we ask the customers to have their DBAs configure and we want to ensure that it IS carried out.  Otherwise, we have lost of design data when the object can't be checked in due to a full tablespace when it can't auto-extend.